# How can I make field mandatory inside datatable based on checkbox input

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller, datatable

I need to   make amount and mode field mandatory if corresponding checkboxes are checked.

```
<Body class="slds-scope" style="width: min-content">
    <apex:form id="disp">
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <div class="slds-card__body">
                <apex:outputPanel id="details">
                    <apex:dataTable style="border-collapse:collapse" value="{!wrapVisitList }" var="viswrap" id="theTable" rowClasses="rowWithBorder" border="2" styleClass="slds-table">

                        <apex:facet name="caption"><b>Create Conveyance</b></apex:facet>
                        <apex:facet name="header">Please fill details</apex:facet>
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">
                                <apex:facet name="header">Select</apex:facet>
                            </apex:facet>
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!viswrap.selected}" id="inputId" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Account</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!VisWrap.ev.Account.name}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Start Date</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!VisWrap.ev.StartDateTime}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">End Date</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!VisWrap.ev.EndDateTime}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Mode of Transport *</apex:facet>
                            <apex:inputfield value="{!VisWrap.ev.Modeoftransport__c}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Amount *</apex:facet>
                            <apex:inputfield value="{!VisWrap.ev.Amount__c}" id="AmountId" />
                            <div id="err51"></div>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column>
                            <apex:facet name="header">Upload *</apex:facet>
                            <apex:inputFile value="{!ExpenseBody}" fileName="{!ExpenseName}" />
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:dataTable>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" action="{!processSelected}" onclick="if(true === performValidation()){return true;}else{return false;}" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Controller :

```
public class conveyance {
public list < event > displayvisits {
    get;
    set;
}
public Blob Expensebody {
    get;
    set;
}
public String ExpenseName {
    get;
    set;
}
public Attachment a {
    get;
    set;
}

String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

public List < wrapVisit > wrapVisitList {
    get;
    set;
}
public List < Event > selectedVisits {
    get;
    set;
}

Conveyance__c convobj = new Conveyance__c();
List < DateTime > Startdlist = new List < DateTime > ();
List < DateTime > Enddlist = new List < DateTime > ();
Decimal exp = 0;



public conveyance() {
    ExpenseBody = Blob.valueOf(' ');

    if (wrapVisitList == null) {
        wrapVisitList = new List < wrapVisit > ();
        for (Event a: [SELECT Id, Modeoftransport__c, amount__C, visitplan__c, Account.name, startdatetime, enddatetime from event where visitplan__c =: id]) {

            wrapVisitList.add(new wrapVisit(a));

        }
    }
}

public PageReference processSelected() {
    List < Event > selectedVisits = new List < Event > ();

    for (wrapVisit wrapVisitObj: wrapVisitList) {
        if (wrapVisitObj.selected == true) {
            selectedvisits.add(wrapVisitObj.ev);
            startdlist.add(wrapVisitObj.ev.startdatetime);
            Enddlist.add(wrapVisitObj.ev.Enddatetime);
            exp = exp + wrapVisitObj.ev.Amount__c;

            try {
                update selectedvisits;
            } catch (System.DMLException e) {
                ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            }

            IF(ExpenseBody != Blob.valueOf(' ')) {
                String fname = 'Expense.' + ExpenseName.substringAfterLast('.');
                insertFile(fname, this.ExpenseBody);
            }



        }
    }


    Startdlist.sort();
    Enddlist.sort();

    convobj.From_Date__c = Startdlist[0];
    convobj.To_Date__c = Enddlist[Enddlist.size() - 1];
    convobj.Expense__c = exp;
    convobj.Visit_plan__c = id;


    try {
        insert convobj;
    } catch (System.DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }



    PageReference p = new PageReference('/' + convobj.id);
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
}

public class wrapVisit {
    public event ev {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Boolean selected {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public wrapVisit(Event a) {
        ev = a;
        selected = false;
    }
}

public void insertFile(String fileName, Blob body) {
    ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
    conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S specify this document is in SF, use E for external files
    conVer.PathOnClient = fileName; // The files name, extension is very important here which will help the file in preview.
    conVer.Title = fileName; // Display name of the files
    conVer.VersionData = body; // converting your binary string to Blob
    insert conVer;
    Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: conVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;

    //Create ContentDocumentLink
    ContentDocumentLink cDe = new ContentDocumentLink();
    cDe.ContentDocumentId = conDoc;
    cDe.LinkedEntityId = id; // you can use objectId,GroupId etc
    cDe.ShareType = 'I'; // Inferred permission, checkout description of ContentDocumentLink object for more details
    cDe.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
    insert cDe;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a simple "required" attribute addition to the Mode and Amount inputs:

```
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">Mode of Transport *</apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!VisWrap.ev.Modeoftransport__c}" required={!viswarp.selected} />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">Amount *</apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!VisWrap.ev.Amount__c}" id="AmountId" required={!viswarp.selected} />
                        <div id="err51"></div>
                    </apex:column>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment EranV. But this did not work for me. I think javascript is the only way in which I am not so good.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript validation called on submit button

```
        function performValidation() {

            var table = document.getElementById('j_id0:disp:j_id4:theTable:tb');
            var temp = false;
            var funcAmount = ValidateAmount();
            var funcMode = ValidateMode();
            var funcfile = Validatefile();
            var funcselect = Validateselection();

            if (funcAmount && funcMode && funcfile && funcselect  ) {
                temp = true;


            }
            if (temp == true) {

                return true;
            }
            return false;


        }
        function ValidateAmount() {
            var Inputcheckbox = true;
            var myTab = document.getElementById('j_id0:disp:j_id4:theTable:tb');

            for (var i = 0; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {

                if (document.getElementById('j_id0:disp:j_id4:theTable:tb').rows[i].cells[0].querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked) {

                    if (!document.getElementById('j_id0:disp:j_id4:theTable:tb').rows[i].cells[5].querySelector('[type="text"]').value ) {
                        Inputcheckbox = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Inputcheckbox = false;
                    }

                } else {

                    Inputcheckbox = false;

                }

            }
            if(Inputcheckbox === true){
                document.getElementById("err51").innerHTML = ' ';
                document.getElementById("err51").innerHTML = 'Please Enter Amount of selected visit(s)';
                document.getElementById("err51").style.color = 'red';
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true
            }

        }
```